# C# Casting using 'as'

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, casting

I have the following code:

```
public class BaseClass {}
public class Class1 : BaseClass {}
public class Class2 : BaseClass {}

public class BaseClassList : List<BaseClass> {}
public class Class1List : List<Class1> {}
public class Class2List : List<Class2> {}

    public void Setup()
    {
        BaseClassList b = new BaseClassList();
        b.Add(new BaseClass());
        b.Add(new BaseClass());
        b.Add(new BaseClass());

        var list = from a in b
                   select a;

        Class1List c1 = new Class1List();

        foreach (BaseClass a in b)
        {
            var o = a as Class1;
            if (o != null)
                c1.Add(o);
        }
    }
```

However, when casting a as Class1, o is always null. What is the problem?

Comment: You are only adding `BaseClass`and no `Class1` to `b`. Every dog is an animal but not all a nimals are dogs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172767/cast-base-instance-to-derived-class-downcast-in-c-sharp

Comment: As doesn't convert one class to the other, it only assigns it if it is an instance of that type

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `a` is not `Class1` object. That's all.
Read your code carefully again - why would you think a `BaseClass` object can be casted to a class, that derives from it?

Answer (score 3):

becasue `a` is a `BaseClass` according to your code:

```
...
 b.Add(new BaseClass());
 b.Add(new BaseClass());
 b.Add(new BaseClass());
...
```

and you can not cast *base* class to *child* class, you have to do it vice versa.

Example:

```
  ...

    b.Add(new Class1());
    b.Add(new Class1());
   ...
```

and after this will be correct:

```
foreach (var a in b)
{
    var o = a as Class1;//CORRECT.      
}
```

Comment: All Class1s are BaseClasses but not all BaseClasses are Class1s

Answer (score 0):

Because you're casting your base class to a super class.
It's like telling the compiler that a "Person" is always "Software Developer", it should be the other way around. So, a "Software Developer" is always a "Person" and an "Accountant" is also a "Person."

Thus,
"BaseClass" is to "Person";
"Class1" is to "Software Developer";
"Class2" is to "Accountant"

So you should add an instance of either a "Software Developer/Class1" or "Accountant/Class2" to the list of "Person" which is the BaseClassList.

Then mark you BassClass as abstract.