# Getting derived type from list of parent types

Tags: c#, inheritance

Given the following two class types, that are both derived classed of the built in ValidationResult class:

```
class ExamValidationResult : ValidationResult
class ApplicationValidationResult : ValidationResult
```

I'm using windows workflows to invoke a workflow that will eventually return a validation result:

```
var validationResults = (List<ValidationResult>)workflowInvoker.Invoke(args)["Result"];
```

Once this is invoked it will return a list of both of the previous object types.
E.G. (As it appears in Visual studio 2013, this is just one item in the list)

[image]

The bottom four propertys in the object are default to the ValidationResult class, but you can see that the derived type is defined at the top.

This would look the exact same for the ApplicationValidationResult.
So my question is how could I cast them back to their derived type with having to manually tell it. (Which I can't effectively do since the list will contain two different derived types.)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172767/cast-base-instance-to-derived-class-downcast-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why would you want to cast it back?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev There is certain propertys in each class that I want to access that I cannot access from the ValidationResult type. That I wan't to access after invoking the workflow.

Comment: But if you want to use properties of a type, you know what type you expect. This means you can use `as`.

Comment: I can't, In the question I have said the list contains two different object types (casted back to the parent type), how do I determine which is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `typeof(yourobject)` or `yourobject.getType()` to determine the runtime-type of an object.

So it would look something like:

```
foreach(var r in validationResults) {
    if(r == null) continue;
    else if(r.getType() == typeof(ExamValidationResult)) {
        //do something
    } else if(r.getType() == typeof(ApplicationValidationResult)) {
        //do something else
    } else {
        //should never happen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to convert each result  to desired type:

```
foreach (var result in validationResults)
{
    var examVR = result as ExamValidationResult;
    if (examVR != null)
        //it's ExamValidationResult
    else
        //do the same check for ApplicationValidationResult
}
```